# Check if logged in user is the author of a post | Django | If-else doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, backend

I want to check if the logged in user is the author of a post in my Forum. I have written some code to figure that out:

```
<div class="right-section-posts">
            user: {{ user }} <!--Output: Admin-->
            author: {{ post.author }} <!--Output: Admin-->
            {% if user == post.author %}
              <form action="DELETE">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="delete-btn" name="post-id" value="{{ post.id }}">Delete</button>
              </form>
              <a href=""><button class="edit-btn">Edit</button></a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
```

They both output the same but the statement returns false! Why?

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="none")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' ' + self.title
```

I tried different ways to get the Current user and the author. Doesn't work to.
(I think you might say that I should use `ForeignKey` instead of ´CharField´, when using that I get this Error:

```
ERROR: Column forum_app_post.author_id does not exist.
LINE 1: ...app_post". "description", "forum_app_post". "tags", "forum_app...
                                                             ^
HINT: Perhaps the intention was to refer to the "forum_app_post.author" column.
```

)

Comment: Please would you share your view function / class?

Comment: I assume that `user` and `post.author` are actually different, but when printed they both display the word "Admin" (perhaps because they are both administrators).  Can you try printing the user ids to see if they are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `author` field cannot be a CharField because it represents the user. You need to set `author` field as foreignkey.

You need to update your model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete= models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Post Author')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ' ' + self.title
```

If you want to check the logged in user from all the registered posts, you should get all the posts first.

```
def get_all_posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter.all()

    context = {
    "posts" : posts,
    }
    return render(request,"my_page.html",context)
```

Then in the html page :

```
<div class="right-section-posts">
        {% if posts %}
           {% for post in posts %}
              {% if request.user == post.author %}
                <!--do what you want here--> 
              {% else %}
              {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
            <div class="alert alert-info">You have no registered post yet!</div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

I also recommend using django-taggit for tags.

Comment: Your Post model is not a recommended structure, I recommend you change it, but according to the current model, the `author` field returns the username of the creator of the post as a string. You can check `{% if request.user.username == post.author %} `
I think it will give you what you want. According to the model structure, if the user enters a username that is not registered in the database, you cannot match the post with the user.